# Most pythonic way to import all objects in a module as their name in the module

Tags: python, python-import

When you import a module, python protects the namespace by importing all objects in that module as `module.objectname` instead of `objectname`. `import module.objectname as objectname` will import the object as its original name in the module, but writing out every object in this manner would be tedious for a large module. What is the most pythonic way to import all objects in a module as their name within the module?

Comment: you may also choose a short alias for the module name such as `import matplotlib as mpl`, so you may call `mpl.whatever` rather than typing the full name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would import everything from modules as their name:

```
from module import *
```

But it's not really good practice. Import only what is really needed and use [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) tests for your code.

Comment: In general, I agree that it is bad practice, particularly with packages. But it can be super helpful to split your own code for a project into two files, one that defines your functions and another that calls those functions for the particular task at hand.

Comment: We also use it sometimes, in for example `__init__.py` and such, but in regular files I prefer writing out imports, so that my linter could warn me if something is missing or imported but not used.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use this form

```
import module.objectname as objectname
```

If you wish to alias the objectname to a different name

Usually you say

```
from module import objectname, objectname2, objectname3
```

There is no "Pythonic" way to import all the objects as `from module import *` is discouraged (causes fragile code) so can hardly be called Pythonic